# saving javascript code to database table, and retrieving it

Tags: php

Everyone know about Google Analytics tracking code. It's a javascript code similar to one below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
```

How can I save following code (or any javascript code, with html tags and comments) to MySQL Table.

Table structure is as follows:

```
id    int
code  text
```

should I write query as:

```
insert into temp values(1,'<script..........');
```

but I think, query would break, and there are chances that un-sanitized data might get store.

So, How can I say any JavaScript, or HTML tag in text field of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example would be:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape all characters that could break the query.